# Usign Mutipart/form-data with Nest.js

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

I'm developing an API with Nest.js and Express, one particular endpoint needs to receive several files (using `FilesInterceptor`) and a body with an array of objects.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
@Post(':id/step/:stepId/complete')
@Roles(Role.ADMIN, Role.STAFF, Role.ENGINEER)
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
completeStep(
  @Body() payload: CompleteStepDto,
  @UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>,
) {
  console.log(payload);
}
```

and my dto

```
export class CompleteStepDto {
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => StepDto)
  steps: StepDto[];
}
```

Now, the problem is when I try to send the payload (using Postman, or any other client) I get the following errors:

> steps must be an array", "each value in nested property steps must be either object or array"

If I log the body to the console I get the following value:

```
[Object: null prototype] { steps: '[]' }
```

Why do I get this weird value? Am I missing something? Do I need to transform the value?

Answer (score 1):

`multer` does not parse JSON strings into their corresponding JSON structure, that's something you would need to handle on your own. So you'd need to add an `@Transform(({ value }) => JSON.stringify(value))` decorator to the `steps` field in this case. And probably then also a `plainToInstnace` for each value that's in the array.